# Smoke Particle Not Playing Continuously

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to play a smoke particle system continuously but at present, it was taking a pause for some time then after again started spawning particles.

This is my particle system inspector values:
[image]

I want particles to remain to continue always not take any kind of pause. What kind of changes will solve my problem?

**EDIT:**
Okay now I understand, exactly this kind of problem running, it does not disappear but exists in a different place.

Still, I can't able to get continuous emission of particles, it getting a pause in mid:
[image]

I have also checked by changing **Emission** from **Time** to **Distance** but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was related to Unity Particle System. Based on other forum discussions, I got the suggestion to update Unity with the latest version because I was using Unity 2018 earlier version.

I downloaded Unity 2018.4.2 and play the game with the same settings. With my surprise, the error was gone and the problem solved.

@TheBatman for giving useful suggestion too.

Answer (score 2):

So lets take a look at some specific settings. `Rate over Time = 10`, `Max Particles = 10`, `Start Lifetime = .5` and `Duration = 1.00`. In order - you are emitting 10 particles per second, allowing a maximum of 10 particles, which exist for .5 seconds, and then it starts over again after 1 second. So, 10 particles are immediately emitted. No more than 10 can be emitted while they are alive, so for .5 seconds no new particles are being emitted. Then, at .5 seconds they all disappear. So now we have .5 seconds per second that no new particles are being emitted. Then, after a full second the process restarts. You can solve this in two ways.

- Lower Duration to .5 seconds from 1.0 seconds so that it restarts right when the particles die
- Increase the start lifetime to 1.0 seconds so that the particles stay until the next batch is ready to spawn

The first solution is probably the better fit.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have applied your answer and edited question with more details so please check it. The actual problem is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Try raising the rate over time in the Emission section.

Comment: From 10, I have set it to 20 but still its not spawning continuously. Also, it started spawning more particle that I don't want.